# Unable to Get Ip address of the http request : Asp.Net [C#]

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page, on which a request from other website drops in. I want to track IP address where the request is coming.

I am using Asp.Net C#  & used three methods

```
1) httpRequest.UserHostAddress
```

Tried Http Server variables as

```
2) httpRequest.ServerVariables ["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
3) httpRequest.ServerVariables ["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

But these methods are returning me my server address. As browser is taking this request  as it is origonated at my end. But i want to get ip address of the page (Site) where the request is coming from. Can anyone help me in this.

Comment: Can you explain your context? Yours users click on a link or you do a redirect? where you redirect? thanks...

Comment: yes a request from  outside lets say Paypal comes to my page http://mysite.com/test.aspx   now i want to track ip Address of Pay-Pal ,which innitiated this request to my site

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you're looking for the Url Referrer properties.

Try

```
Request.UrlReferrer
```

Or

```
Request.ServerVariables["http_referer"]
```

With this you get the Url where the request come from.

Comment: That gives the host, not the IP address(es).

Comment: 2GDev : Actually when i tried Request.UrlRefferrer it returns null

Comment: @FarooqAhmed Check that you don't have a set-up (browser or proxy settings) that strips referrer for privacy. If you do then it'll look the same as if you'd gone to the page directly.

Answer (score 1):

```
private IPAddress[] PossibleReferringIPs
{
  get
  {
    Uri refer = Request.UrlReferrer;
    if(refer == null)
      return null;
    string host = refer.Host;
    IPAddress hostAsIP;
    if(IPAddress.TryParse(host, out hostAsIP))// had actual IP address as host part of URI
      return new IPAddress[]{hostAsIP};
    return Dns.GetHostAddresses(host);//This can throw SocketException which you may wish to catch at this point.
  }
}
```

We can't guarantee that the referrer is set at all, even if there was a referrer, and if there is more than one IP address assigned to the domain we cannot know which served the page as since there is no connection between that server and yours, that information isn't available.

Comment: When i tried your solution it return null because Referrer object is null

Comment: my purpose to post this question is still un-answered how to get IP address of the coming request

Comment: If referrer is null, then either you don't have a referrer (e.g. you go directly to the page, or from a bookmark, link in email, etc.) or the user is going through a proxy that strips the referrer field. In either of those cases there isn't anything you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

`httpRequest.UrlReferrer.Host`

?