# Get IP address used by HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to reach a domain which is hosted over several IP's. When the IP range changes, our firewall will block any requests since the IP is not allowed.

The app will notify us that it cannot establish a connection, but it does not tell us which IP address it was trying to use.

I am using a HTTPWebRequest to create the request, and a HttpWebResponse to receive the response

It doesn't seem like the HttpWebRequest has the IP address in a property when instantiated with the URL, or after the request has been made.

I am hesitant to see if I can get this from the HTTPWebResponse because I don't know if it will have an ip address if the firewall blocks it.

One example that has been mentioned was to set a delegate to:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.microsoft.com");
            req.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = new BindIPEndPoint(BindIPEndPoint1);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static IPEndPoint BindIPEndPoint1(ServicePoint servicePoint, IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint, int retryCount)
    {
        string IP = remoteEndPoint.ToString();
        return remoteEndPoint;
    }
```

[How to get IP address of the server that HttpWebRequest connected to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655713/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-server-that-httpwebrequest-connected-to)

This seemed to work, but I wanted to see if there was another way to do this without having to set a delegate. When I was debugging I noticed that this delegate was running constantly, and I don't know if that would be an issue or not.

Comment: can you do something like this to test 
`Console.WriteLine(Server.HtmlEncode(Request.UserHostAddress));`
for a range of IP address check out this `SO` Post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887428/unable-to-get-ip-address-of-the-http-request-asp-net-c

Comment: @DJKraze I'm using a httpwebrequest object, not httprequest. I can try something similar perhaps.

Comment: I found this then on SO will this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655713/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-server-that-httpwebrequest-connected-to

Comment: @DJKRAZE thanks. I am going to modify the question.

Comment: What does _"When I was debugging I noticed that this delegate was running constantly"_ mean?

Comment: @CofeCaster I had a breakpoint on the line string IP = remoteEndPoint.ToString(); and it was being hit immediately as soon as I stepped over it.